# Can a member variable access the value of a previously defined member variable in the same initialization list (C++)?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example:

```
Cls::Cls(int *p) : m1_(1), m2_(m1), m3_(p), m4_(m3) {}
```

where `Cls::m1_` and `Cls::m2_` are of type `int` and `m3` and `m4` are of type `int*`.

Is this legal? If it is legal, does it do what one would expect?

Comment: Yes if the member was defined in the class BEFORE the member you are currently trying to initialize. Regardless of the order used in the initializer list, members will be initialized in the order of definition.

Comment: @user4581301 why would it be dependent on the order in which it is defined in the class? That seems like an absurd language specification

Comment: @ubadub Because C++ is an absurd language and the order the variables are declared in the class is the actual order they are initialized in, not the way you do it in the list

Comment: @NathanOliver It's not absurd that members are initialized in declaration order---that is necessary to ensure that they're destroyed in the right order. What's absurd is that it's not a compilation error when you get the order wrong in the ctor-initializer.

Comment: All members are always initialized before entering the body of the constructor, so this rule forces the same initialization order as when you do not use an intitializer list.

Comment: So I'm guessing the "best practice" is not to do this? Follow up question, are all member variables in an initializer list initialized before the main body of the constructor is executed? @user4581301

Comment: Everything that can be initialised is initialised before the body of the constructor is entered. So normally, the body of the constructor should be empty.

Comment: All of them, even if the initialization is to do nothing.

Comment: @Nathan Sarcasm? Irony?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Kind of both.

Comment: Best practice is use the initializer list but make sure the order matches. Some compilers will report an error if the order does not match. See if you can get the warning message by deliberately messing up the order and then turning up the warning level of your compiler. While you're there, consider making warnings errors if possible. Warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors and shouldn't be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, non-static data members are initialized in *declaration order*. In order to prevent confusion, you should ***always*** write the member initializers in declaration order. In the case presented in the question, I will therefore assume that the order in which the members were declared is:

```
int m1_;
int m2_;
int* m3_;
int* m4_;
```

Assuming that is the case, the code is well-defined and does what you expect it to do. This is guaranteed by [intro.execution]/12.3, which guarantees that each member initialization is a full-expression, and [class.base.init]/13.3, which guarantees that these initializations occur in declaration order.

Comment: What behavior ensures is the variables are out of order?

Comment: @ubadub I don't understand your comment at all. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If the variables in the initializer list are in a different order than in the class definition, what occurs? Sorry, there was a typo in my original comment, I mean *ensues, not ensures.

Comment: @ubadub your compiler should issue a warning and you should fix your code, but if you insist on having the wrong order in your constructor initializer list, then [class.base.init]/13.3 still guarantees that initialization occurs in declaration order. In particular, this means that your code may be incorrect if the declaration order is different from what I have assumed here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's legal. The init order follows the order of the members in the class.

```
struct C
{
    C() : m1_(1), m2_(m1_ + 1), m3_(m2_ + 2), m4_(m3_ + 3) {} 

    int m1_ = 0;
    int m2_ = 0;
    int m3_ = 0;
    int m4_ = 0;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    std::cout << c.m1_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.m2_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.m3_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.m4_ << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
1
2
4
7
```

But if you modified the member orders:

```
struct C
{
    C() : m1_(1), m2_(m1_ + 1), m3_(m2_ + 2), m4_(m3_ + 3) {} 

    int m2_ = 0;
    int m3_ = 0;
    int m4_ = 0;
    int m1_ = 0;
};
```

The output will be:

```
1
1
3
6
```

Comment: There should be a really big *if* in this answer.  If you declare `m1_` last in the class this won't work.

Comment: Yes you are right. The init order follows the order of the members in the class. If you put `m1_` last the initialiser will use original value of `m1_` when init `m2_`.

Answer (score 2):

This is legal-ish.  If you have

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    foo() : a(1), b(a + 1), c(b + 1) {}
};
```

Then this is fine.  The reason is `a` is declared in the class before `b` and `b` is declared before `c`.  All class members are initialized in the order they are declared in the class, so you could even have

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    foo() : c(b + 1), b(a + 1), a(1) {}
};
```

and you would still be okay.  If you had

```
struct foo
{
    int b;
    int c;
    int a;
    foo() : a(1), b(a + 1), c(b + 1) {}
};
```

on the other hand, both `b` and `c` would be initialized with an indeterminate value and using them would be undefined behavior.